# Unable to execute JavaScript with HtmlUnitDriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

The following code declares a `HtmlUnitDriver` with javascript enabled using `new HtmlUnitDriver(true)` and then creates a `JavaScriptExecutor` like below

```
     WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
     JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) ((HtmlUnitDriver)driver);
```

I find the html tag on which I have to add an attribute

```
      String xpathSrc = "//*[@id='formId']/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/input[2]";
    String xpathDest = "//*[@id='formId']/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]/input[2]";

    WebElement elemSrc =  driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathSrc));
    setAttributeValue(elemSrc, "value", src.toUpperCase());

    WebElement elemDest = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathDest));
    setAttributeValue(elemDest, "value", dest.toUpperCase());
```

then I call the following function

```
     public void setAttributeValue(WebElement elem, String attr, String value){
    String scriptSetAttrValue = "arguments[0].setAttribute(arguments[1],arguments[2]);";        
    js.executeScript(scriptSetAttrValue, elem, attr, value);
}
```

But after all my efforts I am unable to execute the code with `HtmlUnitDriver` but the same code runs efficiently with `FirefoxDriver` or `PhantomJsDriver`. I am inclined to use HtmlUnitDriver because of its speed but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I hope you use latest version.  Please provide your complete case (with HTML/JavaScript) to reproduce the issue.

Comment: This is  the complete code